# How do I import a file from varying directory in Python

Tags: python

I want to able to import different `version files` based on `version_number`.

Here is my directory structure

```
|_ /src
      |_ main.py
      |_ /models/v_0_0_x/m.py
      |_ /schema/v_0_0_x/s.py
      |_ /templates/v_0_0_x/t.py
```

my `main.py` looks like this :

```
version = "v_0_0_2"
from models.$version.models import *
```

I have been playing with some `sys` paths, but I figured there should be a cleaner solution for this.

Comment: You can use the `os` module, `.walk`, `.path`, `listdir`, etc.

Comment: You can use the `importlib` to import a file directly by its path. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html?highlight=importlib#importing-a-source-file-directly) for details.

Answer (score 2):

The exact methodology for using `importlib` depends on the version of Python you are using. I am using Python 3.7.

Inside `models/v_0_0_2/models.py`, I defined `foo = 'Hello world!`.

```
import importlib.util
import os

version = 'v_0_0_2'
path = os.path.join('models', version, 'models.py')
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('models', path)
models = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(models)

print(models.foo)
```

Result:

```
Hello world!
```

**EDIT:**

What I showed above is equivalent to `import x.y.z as z`.

If you want mimic `from x.y.z import *`, you can do these additional steps:

```
globals().update({k: v for k, v in models.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_')})
del models
print(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to change the name of your import for better access later via 'as':

```
    import os.path as p
```

Then you can access the functions of that import by:

```
    p.join("a", "b")
```

Result output:

```
    'a/b'
```

For your project that would be:

```
    import models.$version.models as current_models
```

I am not sure if that is a solution and works with the modules you import. I use that often to shorten module names. This should be available to any Python version.